# Prevent react route unmounting component on state change

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router (v.4.3.1) to render the main part of my application and I have a drawer on the left side with the menu. When a button is toggled in the app header I'm changing the state of the collapsed variable so that the components re-render the css accordantly. My problem is this variable needs to be stored on the component rendering all my `Route` and when the component is updated `Route` is unmounting and mounting it's component.

I've already tried to provide a `key` to my `Route` but it's not working.

My code looks like this and the parent of this component is the one being updated which re-renders my `Main` component:

```
class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.observer = ReactObserver();
    }

    getLayoutStyle = () => {
        const { isMobile, collapsed } = this.props;
        if (!isMobile) {
            return {
                paddingLeft: collapsed ? '80px' : '256px',
            };
        }
        return null;
    };

    render() {
        const RouteWithProps = (({index, path, exact, strict, component: Component, location, ...rest}) =>
                <Route path={path}
                       exact={exact}
                       strict={strict}
                       location={location}
                       render={(props) => <Component key={"route-" + index} observer={this.observer} {...props} {...rest} />}/>
        );

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <TopHeader observer={this.observer} {...this.props}/>
                <Content className='content' style={{...this.getLayoutStyle()}}>
                    <main style={{margin: '-16px -16px 0px'}}>
                        <Switch>
                            {Object.values(ROUTES).map((route, index) => (
                                <RouteWithProps {...route} index={index}/>
                            ))}
                        </Switch>
                    </main>
                </Content>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

I would like the Route just to update and not to unmount the component. is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are having this issue due to defining `RouteWithProps` inside of render method. This causes React to unmount old and mount a new one each time render method is called. Actually creating component dynamically in the render method is a performance bottleneck and is considered a bad practice.

Just move the definition of `RouteWithProps` out of `Main` component.

Approximate code structure will look like:

```
// your impors

const RouteWithProps = ({observer, path, exact, strict, component: Component, location, ...rest}) =>
     <Route path={path}
         exact={exact}
         strict={strict}
         location={location}
         render={(props) => <Component observer={observer} {...props} {...rest} />}/>;

class Main extends Component {
    ...

    render(){
        ...
        {Object.values(ROUTES).map((route, index) => (
            <RouteWithProps key={"route-" + index} {...route} observer={this.observer}/>
        ))}
                            ^^^ keys should be on this level
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That was it. I cannot believe I missed this. Thank you so much.